# Puppet - Variable for package name fails

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet, and I am stumped.

I am installing gcc, gcc-c++, openssl and openssl-devel.

In the code shown, $openssl_devel works but $c_plus is undefined.

Why is puppet setting $c_plus to 'undef' ?

Cent OS 6

```
class torque::prerequisites {
case $operatingsystem {
      centos,redhat: {$openssl_devel    = 'openssl-devel'}
      centos,redhat: {$c_plus           = 'gcc-c++'}

      debian,ubuntu: {$openssl_devel    = 'libssl-dev'}
      debian,ubuntu: {$c_plus           = 'build-essential'}

      default:{fail("Unable identify opperating system. $operatingsytem not recognized") }
    }

    package {'openssl':
      ensure => latest,
    }
    package {$openssl_devel:
      ensure   => latest,
      require => Package['openssl'],
    }
    package {'gcc':
        ensure => installed,
    }
    package {$c_plus:
        ensure => installed,
        require => Package['gcc'],
    }
}

class {'torque::prerequisites':}
```

puppet apply torque_prerequisites

err: /Stage[main]/Torque::Prerequisites/Package[undef]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not find package undef

Comment: You have two cases for each set of operating systems. It's going to find the first one, execute it, and then stop. You should put both the `$openssl_devel` and `$c_plus` declarations in the same set of curly braces. Like you did in your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the original syntax didn't work, but this syntax does works:

```
class torque::prerequisites {
case $::osfamily {
    Redhat: {
      $openssl_devel = 'openssl-devel'
      $c_plus_compiler  = 'gcc-c++'
    }
    Debian: {
      $openssl_devel = 'libssl-dev'
      $c_plus_compiler = 'build-essential'
    }

  default:{fail("Unable identify opperating system. $operatingsytem not recognized") }
}

package {'openssl':
  ensure => latest,
}
package {$openssl_devel:
  ensure   => latest,
  require => Package['openssl'],
}
package {'gcc':
    ensure => installed,
}
package {$c_plus_compiler:
    ensure => installed,
    require => Package['gcc'],
}
}

class {'torque::prerequisites':}
```